# PHP: inserting a row and selecting id of inserted row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After I inserted a row I want to know it's id. Is it possible to get it in the same query with insert? Note that I'm facing the problem on PHP

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: you can use the **mysql_insert_id()** to retrieve the inserted id of a newly inserted row to database

Comment: Are you using mysql_*, mysqli_*, PDO, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

> mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query

Answer (score 2):

Using the mysql_* functions:

```
// after the query
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Using MySQLi

```
// after the query
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Using PDO

```
// after the query
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 1):

or, better, for mysqli/oop:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT ...");
echo $mysqli->insert_id;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php